# Stopping injection of fake analyatic data via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, security, mixpanel

Several web page analytic services, such as MixPanel, comes with an easy to use [JavaScript API](https://mixpanel.com/help/reference/javascript) - accessible like so:

```
$('#some_modal_i_wish_to_track').click(function(){
    mixpanel.track(
    "Played song",
    {"genre": "hip-hop"}
    );
});
```

As of right now, I can just open up a web developer console, and type in `mixpanel.track(....)` and register the event as tracked. Worse still, MixPanel doesn't allow any tracked events to be deleted from their system, and charge per data-point. So someone could use the MixPanel API to track nonsensical events, and there's no way to delete it, and it would still incur cost.

How could I counter this kind of spoofing? There are some limitations here -- the page is supposed to be track anonymously, and requiring some sort of user authentication before any events can be tracked is not a solution. I can't move the events server-side, because we are interested in tracking buttons that pop up modal or go to other external webpages as well.

Comment: Well step one to stop the simple case of the user typing `mixpanel.track(....)` in the console would be to make sure `mixpanel` isn't a global variable. But if the user is sufficiently motivated all of your client-side code *is* accessible to them, so they could work around that one way or another.

Comment: The global variable is included by the MixPanel script, so there's nothing much I can do about that,and as rightly pointed out by you, a determined attacker would get to it eventually.

Comment: You could take it out of global scope by setting `mixpanel = null;` after first making a local reference with `var localMP = mixpanel;`, but yes, a determined person could figure something else out by setting a break point or whatever.